# Restore postgres db from folder

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

i have an old copy of my postgresql db folder (/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/) from my server. Now I want to get the data out of the files. So i copied the main folder to my local machine and changed the postgresql config (/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf) to point to that directory. Also i changed the permission of the main directory to the user postgres. After restarting the postgresql service (sudo service postgresql restart) it doesn't really work.

What I'm doing wrong? (Yea I know, pg_dump is the preferred way, but in this way...)
So my question, does this even work?
Or is there a other way to get the data out of this?

everything is done on ubuntu 16.04.

**Edit:**

the log file after changing the postgresql.conf file to point to the new directory.

```
2017-10-13 06:15:43 CEST [968-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-10-13 00:21:04 CEST
2017-10-13 06:15:43 CEST [968-2] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2017-10-13 06:15:43 CEST [959-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2017-10-13 06:15:43 CEST [975-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2017-10-13 06:15:43 CEST [983-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2017-10-13 06:47:55 CEST [975-2] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2017-10-13 06:47:55 CEST [959-2] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2017-10-13 06:47:55 CEST [972-1] LOG:  shutting down
2017-10-13 06:47:55 CEST [972-2] LOG:  database system is shut down
2017-10-13 06:47:55 CEST [4667-1] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2017-10-13 06:47:55 CEST [4667-2] DETAIL:  The database cluster was initialized without USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL but the server was compiled with USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL.
2017-10-13 06:47:55 CEST [4667-3] HINT:  It looks like you need to recompile or initdb.
```

Ok that pointed me to [this](http://forums.devshed.com/postgresql-help-21/backup-restore-issue-814220.html). The server is a armv7l, whereas the local machine is x86_64 (uname -m). So there is no chance to get the data out of it?

thx, Luc

Comment: "does't really work". Log output? What exactly happens or doesn't? Specifics! Edit the question to add log output at least.

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks for the advice, updated my question

Answer (score 0):

If it's really true that your data directory is from an ARM7l system, and your local system is x86_64, you're going to have some difficulties.

The immediate error about `USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL` is because ARM7L is 32-bit, and cannot pass 64-bit floating point values (8 byte) by-value. Your 64-bit host can. But if you recompiled a custom postgres with `USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL` disabled you'd likely just run into other issues.

I suggest installing PostgreSQL on a matching ARM system to recover the data. Data directories for PostgreSQL are not portable across architectures (for performance reasons).

If you do not have access to the ARM system anymore, an emulator like qemu should be able to help you.

Otherwise, maybe you can compile a modified PostgreSQL (probably starting with 32-bit x86) that can read the data-dir, with appropriate configure options etc. I've never needed to try this.

Comment: The ARM system is still up and running. There the postgresql folder is copied to an usb device, from which i copied it to my local machine. Also on the server i tried to link (changing the postgresql.conf file to point to the new directory) to the usb device copied folder, ended up with the same result.

Comment: Yes, that wouldn't change anything. If the ARM machine is still up, why not just `pg_dump` the database?

Comment: what you mean by "just" pg_dump ?

Comment: so, on the server i tried to link to the backup folders; interesting: for some pg_dump worked, for others an error occoured, that there are no database files ...

Comment: What? I don't even understand. Use `pg_dump` on the running ARM server to produce a SQL dump of the PostgreSQL database, which you can then restore to a new PostgreSQL instance on your other machine. See the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html